# how to make div move left to right faster?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want the div to move left to right on scroll. Which I did.

But, how do I make the div go to the right much faster? Because the speed of the div going from left to right is the same as the scrollbar's speed going from top to bottom. Sorry if I'm not making any sense to you.

Here's the JSFiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/wx8d0a1x/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var $horizontal = $('#horizontal');

$(window).scroll(function () {
    var s = $(this).scrollTop(),
        d = $(document).height(),
        c = $(this).height();

    scrollPercent = (s / (d - c));

    var position = (scrollPercent * ($(document).width() - $horizontal.width()));

    $horizontal.css({
        'left': position
    });
});
});
```

Comment: speed of div depends from how many text you have

Comment: You're essentially asking a math problem. The position is calculated based on the percentage of scrolling you've done, so if you want it faster, then **multiply that** by some number. `var position = (2 * scrollPercent * ...` would make it scroll twice as fast...

Comment: It seems that you want that _div_ arriving at the right side when the window is completly scrolled down. If it moves faster it will arrive at the right side before that happens. Is that what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a multiplier to

`var position = ((scrollPercent * ($(document).width() - $horizontal.width()))*1);`

see fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/DIRTY_SMITH/wx8d0a1x/1/

Answer (score 2):

You can increase the scrollPercent by adding a multiplicative factor or add a factor. For example:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $horizontal = $('#horizontal');

    $(window).scroll(function () {
        var s = $(this).scrollTop(),
        d = $(document).height(),
        c = $(this).height();
        k = 10;
        scrollPercent = k * (s / (d - c));

        var position = (scrollPercent * ($(document).width() -   $horizontal.width()));

       $horizontal.css({
        'left': position
       });
    });
});
```

Comment: You removed a $ before the horizontal.width() that renders an error.

Answer (score 2):

Right now your speed depends on the length of the document. If you want it to reach the right side by the halfway point in your document, multiply your scrollpercent by 2. If you want it to reach the right by a quarter of the way use a multiplier of 4.. etc..

Use Math.min() to ensure that the box doesn't scroll off page.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $horizontal = $('#horizontal');

    $(window).scroll(function () {
        var s = $(this).scrollTop(),
            d = $(document).height(),
            c = $(this).height(),
            m = 2; //Speed multiplier

        scrollPercent = Math.min((s / (d - c)*m),1);

        var position = (scrollPercent * ($(document).width() - $horizontal.width()));

        $horizontal.css({
            'left': position
        });
    });
});
```